# Streaming with go-between in Windows 8

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I want to stream data from a server into a `MediaElement` in my Windows 8 Store (formerly Metro) app. However, I need to "record" the stream while it is streaming, so it can be served from cache if re-requested, so I don't want to feed the URL directly into the `MediaElement`.

Currently, the stumbling block is that `MediaElement.SetSource()` accepts an `IRandomAccessStream`, not a `System.IO.Stream`, which is what I get from `HttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()`.

The code I have now, which does not work:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
request.AllowReadStreamBuffering = false;
request.BeginGetResponse(ar =>
                {
                    var response = ((HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar));
                    // this is System.IO.Stream:
                    var stream = response.GetResponseStream(); 
                    // this needs IRandomAccessStream:
                    MediaPlayer.SetSource(stream, "audio/mp3");
                }, null);
```

Is there a solution that allows me to stream audio, but allows me to copy the stream to disk when it has finished reading from the remote side?

Comment: have you figured it out? actually i do not need to store it, i just want to stream it directly.

Comment: @esskar Not really. Streaming directly works great by just providing the URL, or a `InMemoryRandomAccessStream`. The problem is distributing the stream to two different locations.

Comment: thanks for the information. i tried to set the `.Source` property directly, but it does not work out for me. (I get a null-ref exceptions somewhere in the deep), and i have not figured out how to create a `IRandomAccessStream` form an URL. but i will work on it today.

Comment: You don't need an `IRandomAccessStream`, simply set `me.Source = new Uri("http://...");` and it should work...

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experimented with the following idea, but it might work: You could start streaming the web data into a file and then, after a few seconds (for buffering), pass that file to the MediaElement.

I noticed that MediaElement can be picky about opening a file that is being written into, but I have seen it work. Though, I can't say why it sometimes work and why it sometimes doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would help you to convert Stream to IRandomAccessStream

```
InMemoryRandomAccessStream  ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();)
  {
    await stream.CopyToAsync(ras.AsStreamForWrite());
  }
```